# ActiveRecord #becomes! record not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got some STI in my data model.  There are two types of `Task` records:  `PrimaryTask` and `SecondaryTask`.  So my ActiveRecord models look like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class PrimaryTask < Task
  has_many :secondary_tasks
end

class SecondaryTask < Task
  belongs_to :primary_task
end
```

I want to provide a way to "promote" a `SecondaryTask` to a `PrimaryTask` permanently (as in, persisted in the database).  From perusing the docs, looks like [the `#becomes!` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes-21) is what I want, but I can't get it to save the changes in the database.

```
id = 1
secondary_task = SecondaryTask.find(id)
primary_task = secondary_task.becomes!(PrimaryTask)

primary_task.id          # => 1
primary_task.class       # => PrimaryTask
primary_task.type        # => "PrimaryTask"
primary_task.new_record? # => false
primary_task.changes     # => { "type"=>[nil,"PrimaryTask"] }

primary_task.save!       # => true
primary_task.reload      # => raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find PrimaryTask with id=1 [WHERE "tasks"."type" IN ('PrimaryTask')]

# Note: secondary_task.reload works fine, because the task's type did not change in the DB
```

Any idea what's up?  I tried the following things, to no avail.  Am I misunderstanding `becomes!`?

- Force the record to be 'dirty' in case the `save!` call was a no-op because none of the attributes were marked dirty (`primary_task.update_attributes(updated_at: Time.current)` -- didn't help)
- Destroy `secondary_task` in case the fact that they both have the same `id` was a problem. Didn't help. The `SecondaryTask` record was deleted but no `PrimaryTask` was created (despite the call to `save!` returning `true`)

**UPDATE 1**

The logs show the probable issue:

```
UPDATE "tasks" SET "type" = $1 WHERE "tasks"."type" IN ('PrimaryTask') AND "tasks"."id" = 2  [["type", "PrimaryTask"]]
```

So the update is failing because the `WHERE` clause causes the record not to be found.

Comment: is showing something the log?

Comment: Aha! Good question, didn't even think of looking there. Updating question...

Comment: Did you tried using `#becomes` instead of `#becomes!`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Turns out there was a bug in `ActiveRecord` version 4.0.0.  [It has since been patched](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e95031f55dd54945abebe6e9f8a12e428ada4146).  The key change this patch introduced was to set the `changes` correctly in both instances. So now you can call `save` on the original instance (in my example `secondary_task`) and it will change the type in the database.  Note that calling `save` on the new instance (for me `primary_task`) will NOT save the changes, because of the behavior described in the question:  it will include a `WHERE` clause in the SQL `UPDATE` call that will cause the record not to be found and thus the call to do nothing.

Here's what works with ActiveRecord > 4.1.0:

```
id = 1
secondary_task = SecondaryTask.find(id)
primary_task = secondary_task.becomes!(PrimaryTask)

secondary_task.changes # => { "type"=>["SecondaryTask","PrimaryTask"] }
primary_task.changes   # => { "type"=>["SecondaryTask","PrimaryTask"] }

secondary_task.save!   # => true

primary_task.reload    # => works because the record was updated as expected
secondary_task.reload  # => raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, as expected
```